# Struts2 - Need to change the value of style element of <s:textfield dynamically using local variable

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, jsp-tags

I need to change the value of **style** element **"top"** with the local variable **vTopPosition**.
Below is the code which is not working.

```
<%! int vTopPosition = 255; %>

<s:iterator var="characteristicValues" value="MaterialDTO.characteristicValue">

    <s:textfield id="attribute" name="abc" value="%{characteristicValues}" type="text" cssClass="input" readonly="true"
style="position: absolute; width: 200px; left: 227px; top: <%=vTopPosition>px;  z-index: 31" />

    <% vTopPosition=vTopPosition+25;%>
</s:iterator>
```

Kindly suggest what changes I need to make to make top element dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a property vTopPosition in your action class to make it dynamic.

> In set name attribute was deprecated use var instead.

```
<s:set var="styleString" value="'position: absolute; width: 200px; left: 227px; top:' + vTopPosition + 'px;  z-index: 31'"/>
```

Then in the text field:

```
<s:textfield id="attribute" name="abc" value="%{characteristicValues}" type="text" cssClass="input" readonly="true"
style="%{styleString}" />
```

Comment: Now it will set `vTopPosition` to the value of `vTopPosition`... which seems unnecessary.

Comment: Edited the answer probably more than called for... but this should work (untested).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it but you can try:

```
<s:set var="vTopPosition" value="%{255}"/>
<s:iterator var="characteristicValues" value="MaterialDTO.characteristicValue">
    <s:textfield id="attribute" name="abc" value="%{characteristicValues}" type="text" cssClass="input" readonly="true" style="position: absolute; width: 200px; left: 227px; top: %{#vTopPosition}px;  z-index: 31" />
    <s:set var="vTopPosition" value="%{#vTopPosition+25}"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Hi  your code doesn't seem to work... the code **%{#vTopPosition}px** right next to **top** takes it as String literal rather it should have converted the expression. Kindly suggest what should I do to make it work.

Comment: @MithilShukla Strange.  I did a quick test and it works for me though I'm still not sure this is the best way of doing it.  I just took your code and modified it a bit.  I'm using struts2-core v.2.3.4.1.  Try changing `%{#vTopPosition}px` to `%{vTopPosition}px`?